# Validation api annotations for complex nested objects

Tags: spring, validation, spring-data-jpa

`CustomerDto` has object of `CustomerCredentialDto`. What validation annotation to give on top of `CustomerCredentialDto` object inside `CustomerDto` class, such that it follows annotations given on top of parameters in `CustomerCredentialDto`.

```java
package com.epam.customerservice.dto;

import com.epam.customerservice.models.Gender;
import com.epam.customerservice.models.IdentityType;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.Max;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Positive;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerDto {

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,10}$", message = "Username must be alphanumeric of length between 3 and 10")
    private String name;

    @Positive
    @Max(value = 99, message = "Age must be valid")
    private Integer age;

    private Gender gender;

    private IdentityType identityType;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String identityNumber;
        
        // WHAT SPRING VALIDATION ANNOTATION SHOULD I GIVE HERE?
    private CustomerCredentialDto customerCredentialDto;

}
```

```java
package com.epam.customerservice.dto;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerCredentialDto {

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,10}$", message = "Username must be alphanumeric of length between 3 and 10")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password cannot be blank")
    private String password;

}
```

Not understanding which annotation to give and how?

Comment: Which to use depends on the Spring version you are using, which is the information you have left out. Another thing is which dependencies are you using, if you only have the API it will do nothing as it is only an API (basically saying I have JPA api on the classpath but JPA isn't workig because you didn't include hibernate). You will need `hibernate-validator` (in the proper version for the API and Spring to use) as an Validation API implementation.

Comment: I have used this spring-boot-starter-validation dependency.
Spring version is 3.0.6

Comment: If you **only** used that dependency it should work. So either you did add more (as to outsmart the dependency management) or have disabled auto configuration for parts (like adding an `@EnableWebMvc` instead of using hte auto configuration). With what you provided so far it should just work. Also it is not Spring Validation just the Validation API which is a seperate standard. Also if you want to validate the nested complex object you need to add `@Valid` on top of that field.

Comment: I have used Objects Validator to validate the entities. Similar to this:
```
Set<ConstraintViolation<CustomerCredentialDto>> violations = customerCredentialValidator
    .validate(customerCredentialDto);
  if (!violations.isEmpty())
   throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
```

Comment: as stated (in my previous comment) add `@Valid` to the field (which is also documented in the vaidation api documetation which I suggest you give a read).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the Validation API [documentation](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/jakarta-bean-validation-spec-3.0.html#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-requirements-graphvalidation) (which has **no relation to Spring**) it it stated that for validating nested complex objects or collections you need to annotate those fields with `@Valid`.

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerDto {

    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,10}$", message = "Username must be alphanumeric of length between 3 and 10")
    private String name;

    @Positive
    @Max(value = 99, message = "Age must be valid")
    private Integer age;

    private Gender gender;

    private IdentityType identityType;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String identityNumber;
        
    @Valid
    private CustomerCredentialDto customerCredentialDto;

}
```

Which will instruct your Jakarta Validator to also validate the embedded/nested object. If you don't it will be skipped.

Comment: Yes. I added @Valid to validate the nested complex object & it worked. Thank you. 
Will have a read on it now.